# There is same widget for android?

Tags: android, user-interface, view, android-widget

I need to make widget like on image. There is widgets for android like this?

[image: mac os widget]

SOLVED:

Simple way to do this is use RadioGroup and apply style to it. There is my layout and styles, I hope it will be useful:

```
<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/fragment_search_type"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" 
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" 
    android:layout_marginRight="3dp" style="@style/Searchtype">
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" 
        android:text="1" style="@style/Searchtype.RadioButton"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" 
        android:text="2" style="@style/Searchtype.RadioButton"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" 
        android:text="3" style="@style/Searchtype.RadioButton"/>
    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.25" 
        android:text="4" style="@style/Searchtype.RadioButton"/>
</RadioGroup>

<style name="Searchtype">
    <item name="android:padding">3dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/searchtypepanel</item>
    <item name="android:orientation">horizontal</item>
</style>

<style name="Searchtype.RadioButton" parent="@android:style/Widget.CompoundButton.RadioButton">
    <item name="android:padding">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/searchtypepanel_button</item>
    <item name="android:button">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12dp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

[image: SOLVED]

Comment: do you want the code or are you stuck somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Afaik there's no exact widget like that.
But you could it easily build it yourself using a linearlayout and 3 imagebuttons in it.
Just build up your own compound control.

See
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html
http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/index.html

Comment: May be extsts open sourse widgets like this for android?

Answer (score 0):

Make your own compound View that has several imageviews with a toggle state.